# Is watching cartoons Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, children, cartoon

When I was a kid, I have watched a lot of cartoons. Now I don't have time to watch it. But I have many friends who are still watching it, post a picture and video on their social network and always tell me about them.

I heard that watching these cartoons is Haraam. Especially when it contains stages like [this](http://youtu.be/rr5uNCs_JvM?t=1m30s).

1. I would like to know is this correct?
2. Is this only for this type of cartoon? or for all type?
3. And is it the same Hokm for children, teenagers and adults?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The permissibility of these cartoon is related to their content And it's the same judgment for children, teenagers and adult.
If they contain religious prohibitions like:

1. Mockery of Allah, the Prophets -Muhammad PBUH and all other Prophets-,  Islam, Sharia(الشريعة الاسلامية), monotheism(التوحيدAltawheed), or any Islamic rules as contain the link that you putted in your question.
2. Tarnish Islam image.
3. Concepts contrary of Islam
4. Contain the Beliefs of non-Muslims.
5. Contain obscenity(الفاحشةFahisha) like prostitution(الزنىZeena) and women overdress and uncovering.

In the case of don't contain these prohibitions the children can watch it to entertainment.

But the teenager and adult must be attention for wasting their time in such thing. They must invest their time as their should do in request for beneficial knowledge and other important matters and issues in order to benefit the Islamic nation.

The prophet says in the Hadith reported By Imam Termithi:

> Ibn Mas'ud narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
>   "The feet of the son of Adam shall not move from before his Lord on the Day of Judgement, until he is asked about five things: about his life and what he did with it, about his youth and what he wore it out in, about his wealth and how he earned it and spent it upon, and what he did with what he knew."
>
> عَنِ ابْنِ مَسْعُودٍ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ لاَ تَزُولُ قَدَمَا ابْنِ آدَمَ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ مِنْ عِنْدِ رَبِّهِ حَتَّى يُسْأَلَ عَنْ خَمْسٍ عَنْ عُمْرِهِ فِيمَا أَفْنَاهُ وَعَنْ شَبَابِهِ فِيمَا أَبْلاَهُ وَمَالِهِ مِنْ أَيْنَ اكْتَسَبَهُ وَفِيمَ أَنْفَقَهُ وَمَاذَا عَمِلَ فِيمَا عَلِمَ ‏"

And Allah know best.